# ConfigurationProperties for final fields doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to set data from `application.yml` file to my config class but when I trying to do it I get an error:

```
TestConfig is annotated with @ConstructorBinding but it is defined as a regular bean which caused dependency injection to fail.
```

My `application.yml` file looks like the following:

```
test:
  app:
    id: app_id
```

My `TestConfig` class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.app")
@ConstructorBinding
public class TestConfig {
    private final String id;

    public TestConfig(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) but it doesn't work for me.
Where I was wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to :

https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot#immutable-configurationproperties-binding

You will need to remove the @Configuration from your TestConfig.class.

Furthermore, it's important to emphasize that to use the constructor binding, we need to explicitly enable our configuration class either with @EnableConfigurationProperties or with @ConfigurationPropertiesScan.

--------- Edited -----

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.app")
@ConstructorBinding
public class TestConfig {

    private final int id;

    public TestConfig (int id)
        this.id = id
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

 
}



@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class YourApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? I read this article but the result is the same. I didn't get data from the file.